# login issue with hudson server after moving to new hardware

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I am using hudson 3.3.3 and have just moved my hudson server to a new server and after movement. But i am not able to login to new hudson server. When i give my login credentials, hudson logs shows me successful login:
        hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.TriggerBuilder.perform(TriggerBuilder.java:125)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:34)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:736)
        at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.build(Build.java:181)
        at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.doRun(Build.java:136)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:524)
        at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1495)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:82)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
Apr 12, 2018 5:19:02 PM hudson.security.AuthenticationProcessingFilter2 successfulAuthentication
INFO: Login attempt successful for user

But the screen still shows login option on top right and not getting "Manage Hudson" option. I added anonymous user as admin in hudson-security.xml file and after restart i am able to see "Manage Hudson" option without login. So admin access is open for each user at this time. How can i solve this as security risk is too high with everyone having admin access :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have moved all needed plugins, secrets folder and users folder from your old server. I assume that you have used the initial admin password to unlock the new Jenkins server.

I suspect that after you login, there could be redirect, please double check the URL before and after the login. 
There could be DNS issue. If the Jenkins URL is the same for the new and the old server try to login by IP.

Double check configurations, for example if you are using nginx as [reverse proxy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy).

Comment: thanks K.B. issue was with reverse proxy setup